# Вывод среза массива в одну строку

Tags: c++

Добрый день

Можно ли вывести срез массива в одну строку, как-то так:

std::cout << array[1..3]; // c 1 по 3 элементы

Comment: Таким синтаксисом - нет. пишите для этого велосипед

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, без дополнительного класса или функции это сделать нельзя. Только если так сцепить:

```
std::cout << array[0] << array[1] << array[2];
```

Comment: очень жаль, у меня функция возвращает массив, хотел обойтись без временной переменной

Comment: Напишите ещё одну функцию, которая будет получать массив константой и ссылкой (это даст возможность компилятору хорошо оптимизировать) и второй параметр - индексы/диапазон и выводить нужные элементы.

Comment: @Unknown
Вы хотели сэкономить на производительности или читабельности таким финтом?
Вот вам велосипед-альтернатива:

    template<class T>
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &stream, std::vector<T> vec)
    {
        for(auto item : vec)
            stream << item << " ";
        return stream;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
        cout << std::vector<int>(&arr[0],&arr[3]);
        
        return 0;
    }

Comment: 2Free_ze, простоте написания, изучаю C++, хотел применить финт из другого языка.

2KoVadim, уже понял ...

Comment: @Unknown
Тогда обращу ваше внимание еще раз на то, что сырые массивы в C/C++ - это всего лишь указатели на начало буфера некоторого типа, а операция array[i] полностью эквивалентна *(array + i), то есть получения значения по указателю + смещение. Никакой метаинформации, вроде размера массива, вместе с этим указателем не передается. Подобными свойствами обладают контейнерные классы наподобие std::vector.

Comment: 2Free_ze, доходчиво объяснили, спасибо!